# Angular2 app not served from Apache server

Tags: apache, angular, angular-cli

I have created an Angular2 app as specified in [quick start](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/quickstart.html) guide but by using [angular-cli](https://cli.angular.io/). I created a production build using `ng build --prod`

Then I created a folder by the name `heroes` in Apache `htdocs` folder where I placed all the build files. So when accessing the app through `http://localhost/heroes`, the browser console is displaying 404 error for the js and css files

[image: error]

Any help would be great.

PS - I have a route in the app by the same name as the app folder name in apache i.e. `heroes`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your index.html 
You can change

```
<base href="/">
```

To

```
<base href="/heroes/">
```

and change

```
<script src="/js/shims.js?1484291198182"></script>
<script src="/js/app.js?1484291198184"></script>
```

To

```
<script src="js/shims.js?1484291198182"></script>
<script src="js/app.js?1484291198184"></script>
```

It's working for me

Comment: Specifying the base href value worked. So I didn't make any other changes. Thanks